# How to run multiple instances of Apache Livy server with different ports?

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I am trying to run two Apache Livy instances on the same machine using different ports and pointing to the same Spark cluster.

But when starting the second Livy service I am getting this error:

```
livy-server running as process 24222. Stop it first.
```

Is there any way I can run multiple instances of Apache Livy server on the same machine?

Comment: Check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIVY-401